# Unit Test using MOQ Nested Class & Interface C#

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

Hi I am having the below interfaces and their implementation. Now, I wanted to unit test the `Send()` method which will actually push the message into a queue. 
Since I am new to MoQ, not sure how to get it done.

```
public interface IAdapter 
{
    IChannel UseQueue(QueueDetail queueDetail);
}
public interface IChannel
{
    void Send(string key, byte[] message);
}

public class AdapternServiceBus : IAdapter
{   
    readonly IConnection connection;
    readonly IModel channel;

    public AdapternServiceBus(IConnection connection, IModel channel)
    {
        this.connection = connection;     
        this.channel = channel;
    }

    public IChannel BindAndUseQueue(QueueDetail queueDetail)
    {
        // Logic of creating and binding queue
        return new ServiceBusChannel(this, queueDetail.QueueName);
    }

    public IModel GetChannel()
    {
        return channel;
    }
}

public class ServiceBusChannel : IChannel
{
    readonly string containerName;
    IModel channel;

    public ServiceBusChannel(AdapternServiceBus adapter, string containerName)
    {   
        this.containerName = containerName;
        channel = adapter.GetChannel();
    }

    public void Send(string key, byte[] message)
    {
        // Publish the message
        channel.BasicPublish(exchangeName, key, null, message);
    }
}
```

Here through factory, we decide which type of framework we need to connect and within the factory, we open a connection which passed on to the next class, so that it can be consumed to create and bind queues.
Implementation of `IChannel` is the main class which will be used to actually talk with the queue and topics.

Comment: Have you reviewed Moq's quick-start https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following minimal example shows how to unit test the `ServiceBusChannel.Send` method by providing the necessary dependencies to allow the test to be exercised to completion. It is based on the example provided by the original question.

```
[TestClass]
public class ServiceBusChannel_Should {
    [TestMethod]
    public void SendMessage() {
        //Arrange
        var channel = Mock.Of<IModel>();
        var connection = Mock.Of<IConnection>();
        var adapter = new AdapternServiceBus(connection, channel);
        var key = "somekey";
        var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Hello World");
        var subject = new ServiceBusChannel(adapter, "containerName");

        //Act
        subject.Send(key, message);

        //Assert
        Mock.Get(channel).Verify(_ => _.BasicPublish(It.IsAny<string>(), 
                                         It.IsAny<string>(), 
                                         It.IsAny<bool>(), 
                                         It.IsAny<IBasicProperties>(), 
                                         It.IsAny<byte[]>())
                                  , Times.AtLeastOnce());
    }
}
```

Note: [Moq](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Moq) framework was used to mock the abstract dependencies. Their [Quickstart](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart) provided examples of how to use the framework.

While I believe that the subject under test should not be coupled to concretions, the `AdapternServiceBus` can be used as the entry point for the mocked dependencies as demonstrated above. You can modify to suit you specific needs as I assume the provided code is not the actual code used but an example.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your direction. I have modified the asset by this Mock.Get(channel).Verify(_ => _.BasicPublish("", key, null, default(byte[])), Times.AtLeastOnce()); code and got "NotSupportedException - Invalid verify on an extension method: _ => _.BasicPublish("", .key, null, null)"

Comment: The method which publish message to a queue is BasicPublish(exchangeName, key, null, message);

Comment: @Developer this is why I asked for the actual code. So as to avoid guessing what to answer. Can you update the question so I can provide you with accurate help.

Comment: @Developer, also Moq does not work with extension methods. you need to find out what the extension method calls internally and mock that.

Comment: Have updated Send() method with actual code. Also, it looks like it is an extension method. :(

Comment: @Developer check updated answer. based on documentation here http://www.rabbitmq.com/releases/rabbitmq-dotnet-client/v3.0.4/rabbitmq-dotnet-client-3.0.4-client-htmldoc/html/type-RabbitMQ.Client.IModel.html#method-M:RabbitMQ.Client.IModel.BasicPublish(System.String,System.String,System.Boolean,System.Boolean,RabbitMQ.Client.IBasicProperties,System.Byte%5B%5D)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158609/discussion-between-developer-and-nkosi).

Answer (score 3):

You want to test the `Send` method in `ServiceBusChannel`  class.

So, in your test, you should instantiate this actual concrete class.

To instantiate a `ServiceBusChannel`, you need an `AdapterServiceBus` that allows you to set up your `channel` variable.

Here, the problem is that you depend on a concrete AdapterServiceBus class, so you cannot mock it. You should depend on an *interface* that exposes the actual behavior you want to mock.

Something like IAdpaterServiceBus that declares `GetChannel();`, **(EDIT)** *or declare the `GetChannel()` as a method of your already existing `IAdapter` interace)*.

Then you can Mock this :

```
var mockedAdapter = new Mock<IAdapterServiceBus>();
```

*or*

```
var mockedAdapter = new Mock<IAdapter>(); // if you added GetChannel() to IAdapter
```

then mock the behavior of GetChannel() :

```
mockedAdapter.Setup(x => x.GetChannel())
     .Returns( /* some mocked string value for your channel */);
```

Then you can pass this to your ServiceBusChannel constructor (modified so it accepts an abstract `IAdapterServiceBus` (*or* `IAdapter`) instead of a concrete instance)

```
var service = new ServiceBusChannel(mockedAdapter.Object, containerName);
```

Comment: That is why I did not provide an answer till the OP clarified the question as it is incomplete. Hence my comments first and awaiting response. I totally agree with you suggestion about the abstractions.

Comment: @Nkosi  - So, GetChannel() has to be in the interface? Reason of GetChannel() is not in interface because different messaging platform may have different way of creating the channel and thus it is only part of implementation. Let me know how your view point.